# Why can't I view and edit c_cpp_properties.json in vscode?

Tags: windows-10, c++, visual-studio-code

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

I'm trying to use VS Code to compile and run c++ using these instructions. While completing this step

> Start typing "C/C++" and then choose Edit Configurations from the list
>   of suggestions. VS Code creates a file called c_cpp_properties.json in
>   the .vscode subfolder and populates it with some default settings.

I can't get the c_cpp_properties.json file to open and I get the error:

```
Failed to create "c:\Windows\System32\projects\helloworld\.vscode": EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Windows\System32\projects\helloworld\.vscode'
```

Comment: And why the project is in System folder? Move that folder to desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have no permissions. Your options include running VSCode as admin or changing folder permissions.
But why do you store projects in system32 in the first place? The best solution would be to move it to some other place, where user has write access without admin rights, like Documents.

Comment: Thanks I just assumed that it had to be in system32. Moving it to the desktop solved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, c_cpp_properties.json should be found by

1. Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Searching for `c/c++ edit configuration`.

Comment: note: doing this the first time will actually create a local `c_cpp_properties.json` under your workspace's vscode folder, namely `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: note: The C/C++ plugin from microsoft must be installed to find "c/c++ edit configurations"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is definitely file access permission issues. Opening VS Code as system admin would solve your problems.

While for some other issues (i.e., pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and searching `c/c++:edit configuration` still does not show the matched prompt), **reinstalling VS Code** is **very likely** to solve it.